# How to resume existing tab in resume activity in android?

Tags: android

I have an activity called "Main" with three fragment with tab 1,tab2,tab3. When tab1 is visible and app goes in background and then resume then tab2 is shown to me instead of tab1. How do i resolve this issue.I have made code pls check

code:-

```
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.e(TAG, "onResume called::");
    if (viewPagerCurrentPosition!=0){
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPagerCurrentPosition);
    }
    if (cCustomAlertAdDialog.isShowing()) {
        cCustomAlertAdDialog.dismiss();
    }
    cCustomAlertAdDialog = new CCustomAlertAdDialog(HomeScreenActivity.this);
    // set tabs and fragments in view pager
    setTabAndViewPager();
    /*Reward code*/
    initDrawer();
}
 @Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("viewpagerCurrentPosition",viewPager.getCurrentItem());
    Log.e(TAG,"Current position of tab::"+viewPager.getCurrentItem());
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    viewPagerCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("viewpagerCurrentPosition");
    Log.e(TAG,"Saved position of tab::"+viewPagerCurrentPosition);
}
```

and in `onRestart` i used this line of code:-

```
 if (viewPagerCurrentPosition!=0){
     viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPagerCurrentPosition);
 }
```

Above code is not working in my scenario

Comment: do stuff in on resume

Comment: Save the position of the tab on the static variable and than use that variable like viewPager.setCurrentItem("YOUR_STATIC_VARIABLE"); in your on resume method

Comment: please edit my code i am new

Comment: better to add whole "Main" to help you.

Comment: Did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ViewModel to save tabs last position. And onResume, you can set selected tab again.

Your ViewModel should looks like this:

```
        class YourViewModel: ViewModel() {
        
            private var lastTabPosition = 0
        
            fun onToggleTab(position: Int) {
                lastTabPosition = position
            }
        
            fun getLastTabPosition() = lastTabPosition
        }
```

And in your Activity or Fragment onResume, you can simply set your selected tab by using tabs last position stored in ViewModel.

Your Activity or Fragment should looks like this:

```
    class YourActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onResume() {
            super.onResume()
            binding.tabLayout.selectTab(
                binding.tabLayout.getTabAt(
                    viewModel.getLastTabPosition()))
        }
    
        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View {
            _binding = YourActivityBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    
            val tabLayout: TabLayout = binding.tabLayout
            val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[WidgetsViewModel::class.java]
    
            binding.tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener (object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener{
                override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                    if (tab != null) viewModel.onToggleTab(tab.position)
                }
    
                override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) { }
    
                override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                    if (tab != null) viewModel.onToggleTab(tab.position)
                }
            })
    
            return binding.root
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the default tab which gets loaded each time.
Try this :
  In onCreate and onResume

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
}
```

Let me know if it helps